# Import class conditionally with the keyword 'use'

Tags: php, namespaces, conditional-statements

I've never seen this structure anywhere, so I wonder if there's something wrong with an expression like this:

```
if (condition) {

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

}
```

Comment: Why you need it basically?

Comment: What's the aim to use a condition ? `use` does **not include** anything.

Comment: According to the doc, `the importing is done at compile time and not runtime`, so you shouldn't be able to do that. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Look this at php.net [There is a similar demo about **namespace** usage.](http://php.net/manual/zh/language.namespaces.importing.php#101199)

Comment: The idea was to avoid loading unnecessary code, so I think @Debflav explains it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only thing `use` does is to ***alias*** a class name. That's it. Nothing more.
Instead of having to repeatedly write the fully qualified classname in your script:

```
$q = new \Foo\Bar\Baz\Quux;
if ($q instanceof \Foo\Bar\Baz\Quux) ...
```

You can shorten that to:

```
use Foo\Bar\Baz\Quux;

$q = new Quux;
if ($q instanceof Quux) ...
```

As such, it makes absolutely no sense to want to use `use` conditionally. It's just a syntactic helper; if it could be used conditionally your *script syntax* would become ambiguous, which is something nobody wants.

It doesn't reduce code loading, because code is only loaded explicitly by `require`/`include` calls or via autoloading. The latter one is greatly preferred, since it already lazily springs into action only when needed.

Comment: There is sense in this. Let's say I am switching vendors for a backend API. I want to be able to switch from using one client to another without writing a ton of code to make the swtich. Let's say I define the API vendor in an environment variable:

```VENDOR=SignalWire```

or

```VENDOR=Twilio```

In the class that sets up the client connection, I want to initialize the 'correct client'. A conditional use that loads the right vendor's code would be perfect and then I don't have to conditionally use classes in the rest of the code which might have dozens of 'new's.

Comment: The switch shouldn’t happen at the level of switching out the *class name*! One piece of your code should be clearly aware of the two different class names, and then consciously **instantiate one**, and then you can pass that instance of one class or the other around. That’s proper OOP polymorphism.

Comment: yes, you're right. The way I ended up solving this was to use ClassA as Foo; Use ClassB as Bar; and then conditionally return the properly instantiated class depending on the environment.

Comment: Yes. A further reason why that is the correct way to go is that the constructors may be very different. Even if the classes' interfaces are identical and interchangeable, if they need different constructor arguments, _something_ in your code needs to be clearly aware of which class is which, and you can't let PHP make that switcheroo at the syntactic level.

Answer (score 9):

This will throw a syntax error. From TFM:

> The `use` keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file
>   (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because
>   the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be
>   block scoped.