# How to use PHP Namespace in code

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I am quiet new to object oriented php. And learning step wise new things in it. Now I want to work with namespace in php. I have 2 files in 1 directory. And I want to use `get_name()` function from `class.lib` in index.php file using namespace but dont know how to use it. When I simply include file class.php into index.php its working fine but I want to use namespace instead.

index.php

```
<?php
interface read_methods 
{
    public function read_age($age);
}
abstract class  person 
{ 
    var $gender;
    var $animal;
    var $birds;
    abstract function group($group);
    function people($value)
    {
        $this->gender=$value;
    }
    final public function animals($value)
    {
        $this->animal=$value;
    }
     function bird($value)
    {
        $this->birds=$value;
    }
}

class behaviour extends person implements read_methods
{   
    function get_all()
    {
        return $this->people();
        return $this->animals();
        return $this->bird();
    }
    function non_human($nonhuman)
    {
        $this->non_human=$nonhuman;
    }
    function read_age($age)
    {       
    try {
        if($age > 20) {
            throw new Exception('Age exceeds!');
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->age=$age;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'There has been an error for the age value : '.$e->getMessage().' <br>' ;
    }               
    }
    function group($group)
    {
        return $this->group=$group;
    }
}
$doerte= new behaviour();  
$doerte ->people(array('male','female'));
$doerte ->animals(array('fish','whale'));
$doerte ->bird(array('parrot','crow'));
$doerte->non_human('alien');
$doerte->read_age('19');
$doerte->group('living_things');
print_r($doerte);
?>
```

class_lib.php

```
<?php
class Circle
{
    public $rad;
    function __construct($rad)
    {
        $this->rad=$rad;
    }
    function get_name($name)
    {
        return $this->rad * $this->rad * $name;
    }
}
$Cir = new \Circle(5);
echo $Cir->get_name('30');
```

Comment: Your code is working ? `var $gender;` is "deprecated". If it's the case you can't use `namespace` because you need PHP >= 5.3.0

Comment: my code is working fine and i am using php 5.3 right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Introduction

For your information: "*Function names use underscores between words, while class names use both the camelCase and PascalCase rules.*"

So, I will use the `PascalCase` for your classes (avoid underscore).

### New tree for your app

- index.php
- MyLibrary // Folder - contain all your classes

  - Person   // Package

    - ReadMethods.class.php
    - Person.class.php
    - Behavior.class.php
  - Draw     // Package

    - Circle.class.php

### Adding namespace

**MyLibrary/Person/ReadMethods.class.php**

```
namespace Person;

interface ReadMethods 
{
    public function read_age($age);
}
```

**MyLibrary/Person/Person.class.php**

```
namespace Person;

abstract class Person 
{ 
    /* You should change your var to public/protected/private */
    var $gender;
    var $animal;
    var $birds;
    /* ... */
}
```

**MyLibrary/Person/Behavior**

```
namespace Person;

use \Circle\Draw; // use != require

class Behaviour extends Person implements ReadMethods
{   
    function get_all()
    {
        return $this->people();
        return $this->animals();
        return $this->bird();
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

**MyLibrary/Draw/Circle.class.php**

```
namespace Draw;

class Circle
{
    public $rad;
    function __construct($rad)
    {
        $this->rad=$rad;
    }
    function get_name($name)
    {
        return $this->rad * $this->rad * $name;
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
/** Your custom autoloader **/
spl_autoload_register( function( $sClass) {
    /* Check File Existence. Define a path for your library folder */
    if(file_exists(YOUR_LIBRARY."{$sClass}.class.php")){
        if( !class_exists($sClass) ){
            require_once YOUR_LIBRARY."{$sClass}.class.php";
        }
    }
});

$doerte= new Person\Behaviour();  
$doerte->people(array('male','female'));
$doerte->animals(array('fish','whale'));
$doerte->bird(array('parrot','crow'));
$doerte->non_human('alien');
$doerte->read_age('19');
$doerte->group('living_things');
```

### Go further

About the keyword use: [Import class conditionally with the keyword 'use'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24929521/3361444)

I hope it's will help and that i've been explicit.

Comment: thanks man i understand the concept now and using it in my code :) and learned now